# Odoo 11: when I modify the schedule action Email Queue Manager any field that changes is set to 0 and does not take the value that I put

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I modified two planned actions that come by default:

> Mail: Email Queue Manager
>
> Mass Mailing: Process queue

I set them changing the interval to 5 minutes and after saved, my change was saved as an interval of 0 minutes. When I modify some other field, it is also saved with an interval of 0 and starting to run every second.

Anyone know how can I fix this?

UPDATED 1: The only thing that I could do was install again all my modules in an specific order. Besides I does the automatic actions setup in an specific order too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most addons have different types of data. Some data simply needs to exist for the module to work properly, other data shouldn't even be changed by the user, while most data is meant to be changed per the user's pleasure and is only provided as a convenience.

**noupdate flags:**

This point which is comes under the data files mechanism which comes under the odoo module.

**noupdate="1"** which is not changed during addons updates and not recreated if the user deletes it.

In your cases you are trying to update the data files which were available

**Mail: Email Queue Manager** --> part of mail module under data dir

**Mass Mailing: Process queue** --> part of mass_mailing module under data dir

both of the files created with **noupdate="1"** flag under data files (.xml files)

**Solution:**

Better to create and override the same file in your custom module with **noupdate="0"** with the help of both of the .xml files and upgrade your module again and then you will get your expected functionality in workable.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)